# Flot Charts bars have blurry edges

Tags: flot

I am using Flot Charts for displaying line and bar charts. A colleague complained that the bars would look blurry. I noticed the same on the Flot Charts example page

http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-types/index.html

If you screenshot the bar charts and investiagate it under f.e. 400% zoom, you notice the blurriness. I would understand that a line chart should use antialiasing (at least when it is not in step mode!!!) but why should a rectangular bar be drawn with blurry edges. Is there any way to prevent this?

I tried the lineWidth and shadowSize options both with no effect on this.

I do not recognize this behavior (f.e.) in MS Excel bar charts.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a flot-specific issue. Everything drawn on a HTML  gets blurry when zoomed in. See f.e. the [Canvas tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

Comment: May be that the origin of this problem is the canvas itself. I have found some recommendations like "do not set canvas height/width in CSS but only by attribute" and "translate the canvas by 0.5 in both directions". Height and width seem to be set by attribute in flot. If the translation solves the problem I would ask why Flot does not do this in the first place. Does nobody mind that all rectangles are blurry? By the way, by zooming I meant not zooming the canvas but zooming a screenshot of it in a graphic editor. This was just meant to clearly see the original blurriness.